# Bitcoin in RegTest throw (bad-cb-height) at block No. 500

Tags: transactions, coinbase-transaction, height

Mining in RegTest mode goes well until it's reach block height=500, then server return (bad-cb-height) any idea what is wrong with this coninbase:
02000000
01
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
ffffffff
2a
03f40100
2508000000313130311a00000052797a656e2e33363030582e69732e617765736f6d652e2e2e
00000000
01
40be402500000000
16
001420f897e733695493cc731b0b4b80352fb9a826f
000000000

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0034.mediawiki

Comment: Adding an answer to your own question is encouraged!

Comment: the answer is here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5293244.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is an incorrect implementation of BIP-0034 in my code, I thought the length of height should be at least 3 bytes which I was wrong,

"Coding Enthusiast" says :
"The block height has to be pushed with the minimal number of bytes:
Since BIP-34 activates at block 500 on RegTest, this is ignored on all blocks from height 1 to 499 and from block height 500 it starts being enforced and the invalid push is rejected."

the description of the answer is here: bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5293244.0